# How do I make a textblock's visibility 'Visible' when text is entered in a textbox and the Enter key is pressed?

Tags: wpf, visibility, keyup

When the user enters his/her name in the 'whatsYourNameTextbox' and presses the Enter key, I want a Hidden textblock ('doYouWannaPlayTextblock') to become Visible. This is what I've got so far in XAML:

```
 <TextBox x:Name="playerNameTextbox"                            
             Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
             BorderBrush="Black"
             Height="auto" 
             Width="160"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
             CaretBrush="red"
             FontFamily="Segoe Print"
             FontSize="30"
             ToolTip="Type your name and then press Enter" 
             KeyUp="playerNameTextbox_KeyUp" />

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        x:Name="doYouWannaPlayTextblock" 
        FontFamily="Segoe Print"
        FontSize="16"
        FontWeight="SemiBold"
        Foreground="Red"
        Padding="20"
        Visibility="Hidden"
        TextAlignment="Center"
        TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,0.4,0.2,-25"> 
        Hi,
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=playerNameTextbox}"/>
        - it's good to see you. Would you like to play 'Tables'? If so, just click the 'Choose Game' button.
    </TextBlock>
```

I got the following to work in Windows Forms:

```
 private void playerOneNameTextbox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)

            doYouWantToPlayTextbox.Visible = true;
            doYouWantToPlayTextbox.Text = "Hi, " + playerOneNameTextbox.Text + ". " +
            "It's good to see you! " +
            "\r\nWould you like to play with us? " +
            "\r\nIf you would, just click right here in this box.";
            clickToPlayTimer.Start();         
    }
```

but when I tryto use that in code-behind in WPF I can't get beyond the following:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void playerNameTextbox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            doYouWannaPlayTextblock.Visibility = Visible;
        }
    }
}
```

}

where 'Visible', and everything else I've tried, throws up a red squiggly.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void playerNameTextbox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        this.doYouWannaPlayTextblock.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the correct way to change `Visibility` would be:

```
doYouWannaPlayTextblock.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

Second, are you sure you want to use `KeyUp`? `KeyDown` would make more sense in this case, since it will trigger as soon as you press Enter instead of when you release it.

Third, if your doYouWannaPlayTextblock will be invisible until you press Enter, there is no need to have text in the XAML since the text will be set through code. The code for adding the text would be

```
doYouWannaPlayTextblock.Text = "Hi, " + playerOneNameTextbox.Text + ". " +
        "It's good to see you! " +
        "\r\nWould you like to play with us? " +
        "\r\nIf you would, just click right here in this box.";
```

Comment: Many thanks, Matt - this worked perfectly. I've spent many hours over many days trying to resolve this problem and in all the tutorials, videos and books I've waded through, I don't think I've encountered the construction 'xxx.Visibility = Visibility.xxx'. Can I impose and ask what is actually technically happening in it? Re 'KeyUp' v 'KeyDown' the former just felt more right for me but thanks for your observation. Re the text I picked up the impression from somewhere (not sure where, or why) that it was better  to put such things in XAML than in the code behind.

Comment: @Mike The `Visibility` property accepts a Visibility enum, so thats why you must first call the enum and then the value you want inside of that enum. so thats why it looks like `Visibility.XXXX`